# PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: “”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Database postgresql

I have following migration:

```
class AlterBirthdayInUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_column :users, :birthday, 'date USING CAST(birthday AS date)', default: Date.today
  end
end
```

Migration is started an error:

```
rake stdout: == 20170201162913 AlterBirthdayInUsers: migrating =======================
-- change_column(:users, :birthday, "date USING CAST(birthday AS date)", {:default=>Sat, 18 Feb 2017})
rake stderr: rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: ""
: ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "birthday" TYPE date USING CAST(birthday AS date)
```

How correct point for postgrees in the migration field of type date?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: try changing `USING CAST(birthday AS date)` to `USING CAST(case when birthday = '' then null else birthday end AS date)`

Comment: thank you, respect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It probably fails trying to cast empty string to date, 
change

```
USING CAST(birthday AS date)
```

to

```
USING CAST(case when birthday = '' then null else birthday end AS date)
```

Comment: Awesome way to handle a very specific case when the string is empty instead of null

Comment: I had similar issue, instead of NULL I had 'NULL' eg a string/varchar if you will, with contents of 4 characters, N, U, L, L :)